# @QueryParam/@PathParam parameters in @GET method working despite NOT adhering to JAX-RS rules

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-test-framework

I have JAX-RS API endpoints defined in a class. I have methods in the class such as

```
@GET
@Path("{param1}/{param2}/mypath")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML,           
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.TEXT_XML,            
 MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response getSomeResource(@PathParam("param1") MyClass1 myclass1, 
@PathParam("param2") MyClass2 myclass2 )
{

//business logic goes here

}
```

Now as per the documentation at -- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4867/6nga7f5n6/index.html , @QueryParam and @PathParam can only be used on the following Java types:

```
   All primitive types except char

   All wrapper classes of primitive types except Character

   Have a constructor that accepts a single String argument

   Any class with the static method named valueOf(String) that accepts
   a single String argument

   Any class with a constructor that takes a single String as a
   parameter

   List<T>, Set<T>, or SortedSet<T>, where T matches the already listed
   criteria. Sometimes parameters may contain more than one value for
   the same name. If this is the case, these types may be used to
   obtain all values.
```

In the codebase, `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` don't follow any of the above yet everything works fine on PROD. But when I tried to test the same method with Jersey Test framework, jersey gives me the exception on startup :

```
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of 
the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public 
javax.ws.rs.core.Response
```

On further digging I found that above conditions were required for my `@PathParams/@QueryParams` bindings for `MyClass1` and `MyClass2`. I supplied a public constructor with a single String argument to `MyClass1` and the problem disappeared partly. I tried the same with `MyClass2` but the problem persisted. **`MyClass2` is a static inner class which has a parent class too**. So here are my questions :

1. How is it working fine on PROD but complaining on JUnit test?
2. Are there any special considerations to be made for static inner classes to be used for binding `@PathParams/@QueryParams`? I gave a public constructor with single String arg to the static inner class but the problem still persisted while for the other class (`MyClass1`) it worked. Is there something which I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. What does your production environment look like? 2. What does your `MyClass1` and `MyClass2` look like.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Hi Paul, sorry for delayed response to your comment. The PROD environment has a clustered set up of the application and Jetty is the app server used. Let me know if you are looking for some specific info on PROD environment. Also as for classes, one of them is an inner class (child class of a class from another package) while the other class is a Comparable type concrete class.